# How to find some files and input them to another program in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I have many files with long names and I want to pass some of them to a program.

```
find . -name *A*.b
```

gives me the files I want. Now I want to pass them to another program, something like:

```
program -input A1.b A87_24.b A22.b
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `program  -input *A*.b`  ?

Comment: Can also use -xargs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they're all in the current directory you can just call the program with the pattern. The shell will expand it and call the program with the matching file names.

```
program -input *A*.b
```

If you do indeed want to search recursively through subdirectories, use `-exec`. And make sure to quote the pattern so the shell *doesn't* expand it.

```
find . -name '*A*.b' -exec program -input {} +
```

Comment: Just note that the second form doesn't gurantee executing program just once with selected files; find might divide selected files into multiple sets and execute program once for each

Comment: I don't think the second one is correct, because it executes commands in order but first one works!